# Show that $AB=0 \iff A=A^2$ and $B=B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $\Bbb F$ be a field.

Let $A,B \in M_{n\times n} (\Bbb F)$ satisfy $A+B=I$.

Show that $AB=0 \iff A=A^2$ and $B=B^2$ where $0$ is the zero matrix.

If $A,B$ are matrices that add to be the identity matrix, does this mean that they are inverses of each other, or does this problem require transpose properties?

I'm in need of a serious refresher and am trying to grasp this problem.

Comment: Nothing fancy is needed: Use the condition that A + B = I to write B in terms of A.

Comment: Just because $A$ and $B$ add to the identity does not mean they are inverses of each other (either multiplicative or additive). Think about the case for real numbers. If two real numbers add to $1$, are they inverses?

Comment: in the case where $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$ you can say $A$ and $B$ are complementary projections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have: $A+B=I\,\;\;\;(1)$.

Suppose $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$.

- We have from $(1)$, $A(A+B)=AI=A$ then $A^2+AB-A=0$ hence $AB=0$.
- Also from $(1)$, $(A+B)B=IB=B$ then $AB+B^2-B=0$ hence $AB=0$.

Suppose $AB=0$.

- We have from $(1)$, $B=I-A$, then $B^2=(I-A)B=B-AB$, hence $B^2=B$.
- Also from $(1)$, $A=I-B$, then $A^2=A(I-B)=A-AB$, hence $A^2=A$.

Answer (score 2):

$B=I-A\implies AB=A(A-I)=A^2-A=A-A=0$

Comment: This, however, doesn't prove any of the "iff" implications.

Comment: if you put $0=$ before $AB$ you will get $A^2-A=0$ and similar for $B$

Answer (score 2):

We have $0=AB=A(I-A)=A-A^2$ and $0=AB=(I-B)B=B-B^2$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A+B=I.$ We will show:

$$AB=0⟺A=A^2 \mbox{ and } B=B^2$$

$(\Rightarrow)$. Since $AB=0$, hence $A(I-A)=0$, thus $A-A^2=0$. So $A=A^2$.

$(\Leftarrow)$. Since $B=B^2$, hence $AB = AB^2$, so $AB = (I-B)B^2$, so $AB = B^2-B^3,$ so $AB=B^2-B^2$ (check this), therefore $AB=0$.